# References for libSystem library

Tags: iphone, c99

According to the documentation, iPhone's core OS includes the libSystem library, which I assume contains the standard C library functions and probably more.  How can I find out about all the functions that are available in libSystem?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the functionality is the same. There is an [Apple Technote](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2002/tn2071.html) that lists differences. Search for "Header Files" in that page. Note that this document refers to Darwin and is more tuned to desktop OS X rather than the iPhone OS but it should serve your needs.

Are you having a specific problem with a part of stdlib on OS X?

Comment: I am trying to make sure I got all grounds cover in terms of all the APIs and functions available for me to use in my iPhone coding.